# datepicker on dynamically created row with inputs

Tags: jquery, forms, datepicker

I have a form which has the possibility to dynamically create new row with inputs, the date input on each new row should have a datepicker. I have this almost working, but when a new row with inputs is created, the datepicker won't work anymore on the date fields that are already existing. I have played the whole day to find out what i`m doing wrong, but i just can't see how to fix this.

Here's fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/HermesTrismegistus/vdFaH

My form looks like this:

```
<table id="productTable" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
     <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Product</th>
         <th>Datum</th>
         <th>Tijd</th>
         <th>Minuten</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>   
     <tr>
        <td><input id="products" class="input-medium" name="products[]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input id="date" class="datepick input-mini" name="date[]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input id="time" class="input-mini" name="time[]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input id="minutes" class="input-mini" name="minutes[]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><a id="addnew" href=""><i class="icon-plus"></i></a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The jquery i do have, looks like this:

```
    $(function(){
        // start a counter for new row IDs
        // by setting it to the number
        // of existing rows
        $('.datepick').datepicker();

        var newRowNum = 0;

        // bind a click event to the "Add" link
        $('#addnew').click(function(){
            // increment the counter
            newRowNum = $(productTable).children('tbody').children('tr').length +1;

            // get the entire "Add" row --
            // "this" refers to the clicked element
            // and "parent" moves the selection up
            // to the parent node in the DOM
            var addRow = $(this).parent().parent();

            // copy the entire row from the DOM
            // with "clone"
            var newRow = addRow.clone();

            // set the values of the inputs
            // in the "Add" row to empty strings
            $('input', addRow).val('');

            // insert a remove link in the last cell
            $('td:last-child', newRow).html('<a href="" class="remove"><i class="icon-minus"><\/i><\/a>');

            // insert the new row into the table
            // "before" the Add row
            addRow.before(newRow);

            // add the remove function to the new row
            $('a.remove', newRow).click(function(){
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                return false;               
            });

            $('#date', newRow).each(function(i){
                var newID = 'date_' + i;
                $(this).attr('id',newID);
            });

            // prevent the default click
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: What's `productTable`? Can you create a jsFiddle to illustrate your issue?

Comment: productTable is the name of the table the <tr> are in. I created a fiddle, maybe this helps.. <-- http://jsfiddle.net/HermesTrismegistus/vdFaH/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this, when you add a row, destroy all the datepicker instances and then rebind the datepicker after you append a new row.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vdFaH/1/)**

Comment: Yeah man, you rock! Thank you so very much!!! This thing has bugged me for two whole days ;)

Comment: I do have one more question. Do you also now how i can add datepicker options to it. It seems that it doesn't work when adding it to $(".datepicker").datepicker(); Any idea?

Comment: You should be able to add any options you need. Can you be more specific? Or open a new question?

Comment: As you said, i opened a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095235/cant-add-datepicker-option

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I use `clone()` to create a copy of datepicker.

`$(".cloneDiv").clone().appendTo("#copyHolder");`

Then I remove the "class" and "id" that datepicker has added to input elements.

`$(".hasDatepicker").removeClass("hasDatepicker").removeAttr("id");`

NOTE: Since the input elements are to be cloned, I don't give them the "id" attribute. So datepicker automatically adds "id" to my DOM element. In addition, if the element to be cloned has user assigned "id" which means there will be at least two elements sharing the same "id", datepicker will have some problem to find the correct one. An example can be found in @j08691 's answer.

Finally, re-bind datepicker to input elements:

`$(".inputDate").datepicker();`

All the input elements with class "inputDate" will have datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

Destroy the datepicker and create once again after added the new row. It will resolve the issue.

Here is the example

```
jQuery( ".datepick" ).datepicker(); //Add date picker.

$('#addnew').click(function(){
   $(".datepick").datepicker("destroy"); //Distroy the date picker.

   /* Code to add a new row */

   jQuery( ".datepick" ).datepicker(); //recreating the date picker

})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
This is ur Answer I have done it......

 $(function(){
        // start a counter for new row IDs
        // by setting it to the number
        // of existing rows
        $('.datepick').datepicker();

        var newRowNum = 0;

        // bind a click event to the "Add" link
        $('#addnew').click(function(){
            // increment the counter
            newRowNum = $(productTable).children('tbody').children('tr').length +1;

            // get the entire "Add" row --
            // "this" refers to the clicked element
            // and "parent" moves the selection up
            // to the parent node in the DOM
            var addRow = $(this).parent().parent();

            // copy the entire row from the DOM
            // with "clone"
            var newRow = addRow.clone();

            // set the values of the inputs
            // in the "Add" row to empty strings
            $('input', addRow).val('');

            // insert a remove link in the last cell
            $('td:last-child', newRow).html('<a href="" class="remove"><i class="icon-minus"><\/i><\/a>');

            // insert the new row into the table
            // "before" the Add row
            addRow.before(newRow);

            // add the remove function to the new row
            $('a.remove', newRow).click(function(){
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                return false;               
            });

            $('#date', newRow).each(function(i){
              var newID = 'date_' + newRowNum;
           $(this).attr('id', newID).removeClass('hasDatepicker')
                  .removeData('datepicker')
                  .unbind()
                  .datepicker();
                 i++;
            });

            // prevent the default click
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript error showing in the Chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inline' of undefined
```

This is probably shutting down the datepicker functionality.

Comment: Mind explaining why this was down voted?  This is the root cause of the problem.  Not sure I have the time to go into the jquery.ui code to debug it.

Comment: @Lokase - That's not the problem (or the "root cause"). It's simply an error due to the jQuery UI CSS being used in the example. Plus you provided no way to actually solve the problem.

Comment: Your right.  Should have taken more time to suss this one out. Thank you for the explanation.