# Can't add datepicker option?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a form wich dynamically creates a new row with a couple of form inputs. One of the inputs has a datepicker attached to it. I just managed with the help from here, to make this work. Except there is one problem left, as soon when i want to add options to the datepicker, it stops working...

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HermesTrismegistus/Bt9eU/

And a not working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HermesTrismegistus/TTNEP/

Its about this line:

```
$(".datepick").datepicker();
```

When i add the options to it.. It seems to stop functioning.

```
$(".datepick").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");
```

Does someone knows the solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change both of your datepicker instances to:

```
$(".datepick").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
```

The code you were using works for changing options after you have instantiated a datepicker. The above code sets options when you instantiate it.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TTNEP/2/)**

Comment: Hmm, it seems that after i create a new row with inputs and try to change the first date input, the second get changed but not the first.

Comment: Try this update http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TTNEP/2/. I moved the datepicker code into your function that changes the ID of the input.

Comment: Solved! Thanx again for your support!