# Date picker in dynamic table script issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am working on a form where I need a dynamic table and from date and to date fields in it. The script works fine for the first row, but the datepicker doesnt show up from second (dynamically added) row. I searched on the forum and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093030/datepicker-on-dynamically-created-row-with-inputs) thread where datepicker is initialized. I am not able to understand how can I do it in my code where I need replaced name and value field for the elements. Also start date and end date validation, too, should happen for all rows. Can someone tell me how to proceed in this code?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#addNew").click(function (e) {

     e.preventDefault();
     var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
     var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
     var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

     var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
     $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>');

     $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
     // Replaced Name    
     var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
     var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');

     $(this).attr('name', newN);

     //Replaced value
     $trNew.find("input").val("");

     // If you have another Type then replace with default value
     $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");

   });

   $trLast.after($trNew);

  // 2. Remove

  $(document).on("click", "a.remove", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });


    $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'

        });
        $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({

            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            useCurrent: false 

        });
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });

 });
```